# Gas burners spark continuously unless multiple burners are lit

Tags: wiring, gas, stove

My gas stove has four burners. The two right-hand burners spark/click continuously when their  gas is turned on, even when lit; I've cleaned the electrodes, aligned with with the flame, etc. However, when *both* right-hand burners are turned on and lit, they stop clicking. As soon as one of the two burners is shut off, they begin clicking again. This behavior is not present for the left-hand burners, which operate normally.

Where's the defect: Igniter? Electrode? Wiring?

Comment: If you add the make and model number it may be possible to give you more specific advice (bot probably not).  Press [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/262062/edit) to make changes to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to diagnose an appliance remotely but my guess: Sounds like a logic board problem.   I hope it is.  You have automatic electronic ignition.  It's supposed to keep clicking until it detects the flame is burning.  It's not the electrodes but an adjacent temperature sensor that detects the heat of the flame and stops the clicking.   That sensor should be failsafe, IE, if the sensor fails or the ignitor fails or any part of it fails, it should keep on clicking.

So the first part of your problem is mundane: the sensor failed, it keeps clicking.   But the second part is worrying: If the sensor failed, it should not stop clicking just because *another* burner is turned on.    The problem must be something other than a simple failed wire or sensor.

If you don't know how to diagnose a logic board problem you should have someone who does, look at it.  Meanwhile you should be extra cautious making sure that if a burner is switched on, it is in fact burning.

Comment: I wouldn't consider "keep trying to ignite" to be a "fail safe", but rather "shut off the gas in case the igniter has failed to prevent filling the house with unburnt gas just waiting for a random spark to go kaboom". But otherwise, agree 100%, +1.

Comment: @FreeMan I see what you mean, but I mean failsafe in the limited way that most failures of the flame detector probe/wire/circuit, including the most typical ones, will result in a "no flame" state, thus continued electronic ignition and no collection of gas in the room.

Comment: @FreeMan what you want is four separate intelligent control valves, such as the ones in a boiler with electronic ignition or the ones inside the gas oven.   Are there kitchen ranges that have that?  Those valves are expensive, no?

Comment: Or just one for the hole stove top/oven. They're probably expensive, but I'd prefer that. Haven't cooked on a gas stove in _ages_ and don't recall any issues with ignition _way_ back when I did, so couldn't say if they "used to make 'em that way", but, logically, to me, that would be the way to do it. Maybe it isn't the way it's actually done.

Comment: With one valve, one ignitor fail would shut down all burners.  A range like that would not sell well.  My range, only 8 years old, has no safety mechanism on it.  Turn on the gas, it flows.  Up to you to ignite it.  My mom's, 20+ years old, forces you to *hold down* the ignitor til it senses heat.  The failsafe is in the manual control valve so it will not "keep clicking" like OP's, it's not THAT automatic. My MIL's also flows regardless of ignition but has a clever master gas switch with a pilot light, great idea.  IDK why that isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Due to possible contamination, the "flame is on" thermocouple needs attention.

Locate and clean till it is shiny metal

If that does not help replace it.

There also might be a problem with the control board, but can't say anything without model and schematic.

It is also possible that the circuit is designed also to automatically continues to ignite the neighboring burner for safety reasons. So without the actual schematic one cannot definitely answer the question